# xcode server with JIRA

Tags: continuous-integration, jira, xcode-server

I am trying to send Xcode server build/test result to JIRA. But not sure what I can do here. I assume I can write a script to listen to the event of the Xcode server, when a build is completed then call the JIRA api. This is technically feasible but if someone has done it before, I would love to hear the process.

Answer (score 0):

A bot with a post-integration script isn't sufficient to the task? Set the bot to run on "Success" (personally, I run on warnings and analyzer suggestions, as they interrupt "success" state but for my purposes are a kind of "success"). Fire off a cURL to the JIRA API in that script. Pretty much a done deal, no?

It feels to me like you're focused more on the "listen to the event of Xcode server" but Xcode Server already provides that service to you via bot integrations.